# How do I display high quality images with Python?

Tags: python, json, image, extract

##Wrote this code:

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(bot.context, 'lola.eko_')

posts = profile.get_posts()

for index, post in enumerate(posts, 1):
bot.download_post(post, target=f"{profile.username}_{index}")

##and I got this error message:

JSON Query to api/v1/media/2689264607951889570/info/: HTTP error code 403. [retrying; skip with ^C]
JSON Query to api/v1/media/2689264607951889570/info/: HTTP error code 403. [retrying; skip with ^C]
JSON Query to api/v1/media/2689264607951889570/info/: HTTP error code 403. Unable to fetch high quality image version of .

##Do I need a particular package or what's the possible solution that will help me get around this? Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough info in your post to help you figure out what the root of the issue is. Please make a [mre], or at least read the [tour], the [ask] page, and the [help/on-topic] to get a better idea of what is required in each question posted on StackOverflow. It's obvious that you're getting a `403`, sure, but we don't know what API this is, whether or not you should have permission, or what you're using in your code to authenticate your requests.

Comment: A 403 is forbidden.  You don't have permission to get the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.